# UIButton in custom UIView not responding to events

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a custom `UIView` which I can use throughout the whole application in different places.
It basically looks like this:

```
@interface BottomBar : UIView
{
    UIImageView *imageView;
    UILabel *nameLabel;
    UIButton *playPauseButton;
}
@end

@implementation BottomBar

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 524.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    if (self) {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 2.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
        nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 2.0, 180.0, 40.0)];
        playPauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265.0, 2.0, 40.0, 40.0)];

        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.200 alpha:1.000]];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NowPlaying.png"]];
        [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue UltraLight" size:26.0]];
        [nameLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.000 alpha:0.650]];
        [nameLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 2.0)];
        [playPauseButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        [playPauseButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [playPauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self addSubview:imageView];
        [self addSubview:nameLabel];
        [self addSubview:playPauseButton];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

I snipped some methods, the `buttonPressed:(id)sender` method is included, don't worry. But the `UIButton` won't respond to the event, or to any event. It doesn't even highlight itself. 
I did the initialisation before through a nib file with `[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BottomBar" [...]] objectAtIndex:0];` and connected the `IBOutlets` (which worked fine) and the `IBAction`s, which obviously, doesn't worked as well.

Any ideas how to solve it?

**Edit:** I think it's more related to this part, because it seems like my `UIViewController` is overlapping, although it's defined as a freeform and definitely not overlapping. I've just tested it with the `UIWindow` color set to red.

Here is the code anyway:

```
OverviewViewController *ovc = [[OverviewViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ovc];
[[self window] setRootViewController:nvc];

bottomBar = [[BottomBar alloc] init];
[[self window] addSubview:bottomBar];
[[self window] bringSubviewToFront:bottomBar];
```

OverviewViewController is defined in a xib as 320x460, so it should have 44px on the bottom for my bar.

**Edit2:** No, the resizing of the `UIViewController` isn't working. Any ideas how?

Comment: Are you saying that your UIViewController view overlapping Bottom Bar ?

Comment: Exactly. I solved it with a `UIViewController` who contains the other viewControllers.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that none of the views/labels are hiding your button (even a transparent view would not allow you to click). Also make sure that the bounds of that button is equal to its frame.

Comment: Take a look at the code snippet. You can see the parent view is 44px high. Every child is maximum 40px high and set to y position of 2. 
Also those are just three views. And all of them don't overlap.

Sorry, but you could've answered this by yourself just by looking at the code.

Comment: I 've check the code even before my answer and it looks correct. However, i dont know what you doing in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, most of time imageView would not allow you to click the button, comments the imageView code and then try it..

Comment: Doesn't help, even commenting everything out and just having the bare and default button there helps.

Comment: playPauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 265.0, 40.0, 40.0)];        try this code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
playPauseButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(265.0, 2.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
```

It should be

```
playPauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[playPauseButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265.0, 2.0, 40.0, 40.0)];
```

The problem is you are not defining the `UIButton Type` in your code that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

My `UIViewController` was overlapping the `UIView` and therefore the taps couldn't be recognised.